# Python throwing an indented block error. not seeing it

Tags: python

My Python code is throwing an `expected indented block` error right after the `elif`.

I am having trouble seeing where the indenting mistake is.

What indentation mistake have I made?

```
def expandProcedure(node, queue):
    successors = []
    n = 4
    while (n > 0):
        parent = node
        depth = node[2] + 1
        pathCost = node[3] + 1
        newState = testState(node[0], n)

        if newState == 0:
            ## do nothing
        elif inQueue(newState[0], queue):
            #do nothing

        else:
            s = makeNode(newState, parent, depth, pathCost)
            successors.insert(0, s)

    n = n - 1

return successors
```

Comment: `## do nothing` is not counted so you have an empty block, if you don't want to do anything use `pass`

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a null block.  Use the **pass** (non-)command:

```
if newState == 0:
    pass
elif inQueue(newState[0], queue):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make empty blocks in Python. At least put `pass` there if you want a real do-nothing:

```
if newState == 0:
    pass
elif newState != 0:
    pass
```